# Count retornando valor null com Query Builder Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

Estou com um problema, tenho uma query que busca os dados do funcionário mais o somatório de dias de férias e faltas que um funcionário possui. A query está funcionando se o funcionário tiver algum dia registrado nas tabelas, falta e férias. O problema é que se esse funcionários não tiver nenhum registro de faltas ou férias a query não funciona.

Preciso que quando estiver `null` nessas tabelas, setar o valor 0.

```
$servidores = DB::table('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor')
->join('sch_decom.tb_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula', '=', 'sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula')
->join('sch_sismapa.tb_falta','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor')
->join('sch_sismapa.tb_ferias','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor')
->select('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.*',DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor) as faltas'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor) as ferias'))
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria',$request->cd_secretaria)
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia',$request->id_referencia)
->groupBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_dias',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_lancado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_aprovado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.ds_observacao',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_grat_reuniao')
->orderby('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', 'asc')
->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'asc')
->skip($partes)
->take(300)
->get();
```

Já tentei utilizar o `IFNULL` mas acho que estou utilizando de maneira errada.

OBS: Estou utilizando *POSTGRESQL* e *Laravel 5.5*.

Comment: se rodar a query diretamente no banco de dados ela funciona ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que seu problema está no `join` onde o certo seria utilizar [leftJoin](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) para férias ou faltas, porque caso o `innerjoin` não encontre nada ele e um parâmetro exclusivo, ja o `leftJoin` não seria.

Teste o seguinte eloquent, e me fale se funcionou:

```
$servidores = DB::table('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor')
->join('sch_decom.tb_servidor', 'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula', '=', 'sch_decom.tb_servidor.nr_matricula')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_falta','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor')
->leftJoin('sch_sismapa.tb_ferias','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id', '=', 'sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor')
->select('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.*',DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_falta.id_servidor) as faltas'),DB::raw('COUNT(sch_sismapa.tb_ferias.id_servidor) as ferias'))
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria',$request->cd_secretaria)
->where('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia',$request->id_referencia)
->groupBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.id_referencia','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_matricula',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_secretaria','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.nr_dias',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_lancado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_aprovado','sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.ds_observacao',
    'sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.st_grat_reuniao')
->orderby('sch_sismapa.tb_servidor.cd_departamento', 'asc')
->orderBy('sch_decom.tb_servidor.nm_servidor', 'asc')
->skip($partes)
->take(300)
->get();
```

Link:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou.